# Update java version in Camunda Platform

Tags: java, camunda

I would like to upgrade Java JDK from 1.8.0_212 to 1.11.0 in Camunda Platform. I am using Camunda 7.11.0 and deploying it as container. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Which camunda distribution you are using? Is this Tomcat or Spring boot ? Who created Docker image you or provided by camunda ? Answer will depend based on the distribution.

Comment: @Sahota we are using docker image provided by the camunda itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is Official Docker image from Camunda you can try this

1. Clone the camunda repo https://github.com/camunda/docker-camunda-bpm-platform
2. Switch/checkout to specific version branch/tag 7.11.0
3. Modify the Dockerfile base docker image to image which has jdk11 built-in and rebuild image .

I know this requires knowledge of docker/git and how camunda builds their images. You have to reverse engineer this repo as well.